# React Accordion transition ,

Tags: reactjs

I have this Accordion , and for some reason my transition not working on Accordion Item component. Please help me , I'm during learning process of React. CODE WITH CSS BELOW PS. Console log shows that onclick both classes with transtion are added , but not performing
CSS

```
.accordion {
    display: flex;
    // justify-content: space-between;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: linear-gradient(#bdc3c7, #2c3e50);

    h1 {
        letter-spacing: 0.04rem;
        margin: 15px;
        font-size: 4rem;
    }
    .classContainer {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;

        width: 100%;

        .accordionItem {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
            transition: max-height 5s ease-out;
            max-height: 0;
            width: 98%;
            // overflow: hidden;
            border-radius: 4px;

            &.animated {
                max-height: 450px;
                transition: max-height 5s ease-in;
                background-color: green;
            }

            label {
                font-weight: 600;
                text-align: left;
                margin-bottom: 5px;
                padding: 8px 0px 8px 8px;
            }

            input {
                background-color: red;
                width: 50%;
                height: 30px;
                margin: 4px 0px 4px 4px;
                border: solid 1px;
                border-radius: 4px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
                -moz-border-radius: 4px;
                -ms-border-radius: 4px;
                -o-border-radius: 4px;
            }
        }
    }
}


import styles from "./index.module.scss";
import dataForVendors from "../../VendorDataArray";
import AccordionItem from "../AccordionItem";
import { useState } from "react";
import AccordionCard from "../AccordionCard";

const VendorCard = () => {
    /// Function to create unique values array
    const uniqueVendors = dataForVendors.filter(function (item, index) {
        return (
            index ===
            dataForVendors.findIndex(function (obj) {
                return item.name === obj.name;
            })
        );
    });

    // Function to group the obejct with same names
    /// Array of objects nested structure tree
    const groupedVendors = [];
    for (const uniq of uniqueVendors) {
        const structure = {
            vendor_id: uniq.id,
            vendor_name: uniq.name,
            group: [],
        };
        dataForVendors.forEach((v) => {
            if (v.name === uniq.name) {
                structure.group.push(v);
            }
        });

        groupedVendors.push(structure);
    }

    // Accordion component the one is not visible
    const AccordionItem = ({ activeIndex }) => {
        return (
            <div
                className={
                    !activeIndex ? `${styles.accordionItem} ${styles.animated} ` : ""
                }
            >
                <label htmlFor="myInput">Name</label>
                <input type="text" />
                <label htmlFor="">Category</label>
                <input type="text" />
                <label htmlFor="">Address</label>
                <input type="text" />
                <label htmlFor="">Latitude</label>
                <input type="text" />
                <label htmlFor="">Longitude</label>
                <input type="text" />
            </div>
        );
    };

    // Function to show div with input and details
    const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(-1);
    const handleClick = (index) => {
        setActiveIndex(index === activeIndex ? -1 : index);
    };

    return (
        <div className={styles.accordion}>
            <h1>Vendors</h1>
            {groupedVendors.map((card, index) => (
                <div
                    key={card.vendor_id}
                    className={styles.classContainer}
                    onClick={() => handleClick(index)}
                >
                    <AccordionCard>
                        <h3>{card.vendor_name}</h3>
                    </AccordionCard>
                    {/* <div className={styles.vendorData}></div> */}
                    {index === activeIndex && <AccordionItem />}
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};

export default VendorCard;
```

Itry set state and max-height and didin't work . I want accordion item expend with transition and back with it

Comment: It's hard to tell without a functional [mre] (ideally as a snippet), but are you sure you want to toggle both the `accordionItem` and `animated` classes? I would have expected just `animated` to be added based on `activeIndex`

Comment: Is still confusing for me on the beginning , but I did not give up , and I kind of love this problem-solving after a couple of months JS and React. Thank you

Comment: Could you try to make  a minimal reproducible example as suggested in [stackblizt](https://stackblitz.com/) or [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) so we can more easily provide help?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/p/github/lukanogaj/vendor/main?import=true&workspaceId=ece9501d-9f41-4d53-81e0-767704f01a5e

Comment: I have full repository from Git Hub , please be patient , I am new